# sed $ mismatch start of line with double quote

Tags: bash, sed

I am having a weird behavior with `bash` and `sed` (on a Debian9 machine), it may be something related to the file ([file1.CSV](https://gist.github.com/cccnrc/72d302266ea42d0b2eb4869932bd7db8/archive/d983ebe554ad5e963f36478f74391e3e0dc92dab.zip)) I'm using but I cannot figure out what.

Here we go, if I try to replace the endline with something through `sed` it mismatch the linestart (that is a `"`):

```
head app/datasets/liste_random/file0.csv  | sed 's/$/@/'

@id","stratum","block.id","block.size","treatment"
@PC_LR01","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR1",4,"COLC"
@PC_LR02","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR1",4,"COLC"
@PC_LR03","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR1",4,"SOC"
@PC_LR04","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR1",4,"SOC"
@PC_LR05","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR2",4,"SOC"
@PC_LR06","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR2",4,"COLC"
@PC_LR07","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR2",4,"COLC"
@PC_LR08","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR2",4,"SOC"
@PC_LR09","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR3",2,"SOC"
```

I looked for possible reasons but I could find nothing interesting, sure it is something stupid but I could not figure out what was the problem.

If I `echo` a line it works properly, so think it is the file

```
echo '"id","stratum","block.id","block.size","treatment"
"PC_LR01","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR1",4,"COLC"'  | sed 's/$/@/g'

"id","stratum","block.id","block.size","treatment"@
"PC_LR01","Piacenza_LR","PC_LR1",4,"COLC"@
```

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Your files have DOS newlines -- that is to say, two-character `<CR><LF>` ("carriage return" / "linefeed") sequences, as opposed to UNIX newlines, which have only a `<LF>`. Thus, `sed` is adding content after the `<CR>` and before the `<LF>`, so it's printed at the beginning of each line (after the carriage has been returned -- the cursor moved to the left -- but before the next line is fed -- the cursor moved down).

Comment: Run `dos2unix` on your file to remove the carriage returns.

Comment: Yeah, crlf, is the culprit, or maybe `tr -d "\r" < file1.CSV | sed 's/$/@/'`

Comment: (as context for what Jetchisel is suggesting above, `\r` is another way to write the `<CR>` character, just as `\n` is the equivalent way to express an `<LF>`; thus, one could also say that UNIX newlines are just `\n`, whereas DOS/Windows ones are `\r\n`).